# Phonegap dont show video inline correctly on Android 4.4

Tags: cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to use tag  in my project. I know the video can not be in folder wwww, so I save me video in cordova.file.dataDirectory and update source tag with the link. My player play the video, but just the audio, no image. When I click in full screen, the image pops up, but when I return, it fades away. I tried MP4 and webm format.

I'm use Android 4.4, Phonegap 6.4.5 and Cordova 6.5.0. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you using Crosswalk?

Comment: no, Crosswalk take a lot of space. =/ In Android 5, works fine!

Comment: You'll either need to use Crosswalk for a consistent experience on Android 4.4, OR, you'll need to investigate plugins that handle the video. IIRC, none of them will do inline video, though, so if that's a requirement, I'd wager that you'll have to use Crosswalk if you intend on supporting Android < 5.